# Delete offset in boostrap respect to wieport size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm this simple situation

```
<div class="row full" id="slogan">

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 text-center" id="girl">
            <img src="<?php the_field('immagine_slogan'); ?>" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center" id="colonna-testo-slogan">
            <div class="testo-slogan">
            <h2><?php the_field('titolo_slogan'); ?></h2>
            <?php the_field('descrizione_slogan'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

I would like that in the -col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1- when wieport size is below X px delete the offset !
Is it possible ??

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query. For example, where X = 800 ..

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .reset-offset.col-sm-offset-1 {
      margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/vFfstYZnAH

Comment: But this solution edit every  .col-sm-offset-1 in my site when max-width: 400px, right?
And I don't want this situation, but only for that !

Comment: Then use a custom class name in the column.

Comment: Or select `#slogan > .col-sm-offset-1 {}` but the custom class `.reset-offset` is a way better solution

Comment: Great. Please accept the anwser so others know it is resolved